# crawling a website with solr6.4.1

Tags: solr, nutch

I am trying to crawl a website in Solr 6.4.1. I assume that Nutch is OOTB shipped with Solr. I am using the below command to crawl a website

```
java -Ddata=web -Dc=corename -jar post.jar (URLName starting from https)
```

I am getting a below error:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url:
```

Comment: solr.log:Error adding field 'stream_size'='null' msg=For input string: "null"

Comment: Is there any configuration changes to be made to make solr crawl a website

Comment: Can anyone please guide me on correct syntax to crawl a website in solr 6.4.1

Comment: As far as I am concerned, Nutch is not shipped with solr. They are two completely separate software products. You will have to handle them separately.

Comment: There is internal nutch shipped with solr 6.4.0 version so inorder to crawl a URL we need not to have additional Nutch installed.............................java -Ddata=web -Dc=corename -jar post.jar (URL)

Comment: I have got my URL crawling done...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think SimplePostTool works for URLs, despite the doc.  It will always read it as a folder, and not a URL.

If you need to crawl, I think you need to use a Linux machine.  The bin/post script works just fine from Linux.